# Shuffle content in a YAML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have this YAML file and I have a list with the strings I want to shuffle:

List:

```
['StmRsBgmSea02', 'StmRsBgmShopRadio', 'StmRsBgmSea01', ...]
```

This is not the complete list.

YAML file:

```
Version: 3
IsBigEndian: False
SupportPaths: False
HasReferenceNodes: False
root:
  StageInfoList:
    - Name: SeaWorldHomeStage
      StageScenarioInfoList:
        - ScenarioNo: !l 0
          StagePlayInfoList:
            - {Name: WorldMain, ResourceName: StmRsBgmSea02}
            - {Name: Shop, ResourceName: StmRsBgmShopRadio}
        - ScenarioNo: !l 1
          StagePlayInfoList:
            - {Name: WorldMain, ResourceName: StmRsBgmSea01}
            - {Name: Boss, ResourceName: StmRsBgmBossHaikai_B}
            - {Name: Town, ResourceName: StmRsBgmSea01beach}
            - {Name: BossDead, ResourceName: WsdRsBgmJgSeaFountain}
    - Name: SeaWorldCostumeStage
      StageScenarioInfoList:
        - ScenarioNo: !l 0
          StagePlayInfoList:
            - {Name: CostumeRoom, ResourceName: WsdRsBgmMarioPlayHula}
```

The file is 800 lines long. I have a list with every name that comes after `ResourceName:`.

I want that every value after `ResourceName:` will be replaced with one random value from the list. It is important that the string will be deleted from the list after one `RessourceName` will be randomized. So that no value occurs twice.

Comment: what approaches have you tried for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load data from YAML (or JSON) you get an easy to recurse in data structure: everything is either a dict, a list or a value. You should make a routine that takes along the list of substitute values (here `[v0, v1, v2, ...]` while recursing and assign them whenever you find a key named `ResourceName`.

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import random
import ruamel.yaml


def recur(d, sub, key):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == key:
                d[key] = selected = random.choice(sub)
                sub.remove(selected)
                continue
            recur(v, sub, key)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            recur(elem, sub, key)
        

substitutes =['v0', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v9']
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(Path('input.yaml'))
recur(data, substitutes, 'ResourceName')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Version: 3
IsBigEndian: false
SupportPaths: false
HasReferenceNodes: false
root:
  StageInfoList:
    - Name: SeaWorldHomeStage
      StageScenarioInfoList:
        - ScenarioNo: !l 0
          StagePlayInfoList:
            - {Name: WorldMain, ResourceName: v1}
            - {Name: Shop, ResourceName: v5}
        - ScenarioNo: !l 1
          StagePlayInfoList:
            - {Name: WorldMain, ResourceName: v2}
            - {Name: Boss, ResourceName: v0}
            - {Name: Town, ResourceName: v4}
            - {Name: BossDead, ResourceName: v3}
    - Name: SeaWorldCostumeStage
      StageScenarioInfoList:
        - ScenarioNo: !l 0
          StagePlayInfoList:
            - {Name: CostumeRoom, ResourceName: v7}
```

If appropriate, you might want to check if substitutes is empty
after calling `recur()`

Comment: Thanks, I learned many things about ruamel.yaml. It worked in my script.